# Why doesn't CSS example from a tutorial work for me?

Tags: html, css

I am doing a .net tutorial which tells me to grab a bootstrap.css variant from boots watch, but it doesn't look right when I run my project. I can't figure out why. This is how its supposed to look:

The desired behavior is that it looks like this:
[image: bootswatch]

This is what I am getting:

[image: jsfiddle and .net result looks like tihs]

https://jsfiddle.net/twbpno0v/3

This is the shortest code to reproduce the problem:

```
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/minty/bootstrap.css">

</head>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                NAME
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>home</li>
                    <li>about</li>
                    <li>contact</li>
                </ul>
               log
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My question, is why? What am I missing?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Doesn't my jsfiddle link provide all that?

Comment: **IN THE QUESTION ITSELF!** Links to third party sites move, get changed and deleted helping no one in the future.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't want to post that entire bootstrap file in there, is this sufficient?

Comment: **THE SHORTEST CODE NECESSARY TO REPRODUCE THE PROBLEM!"** Yes. Possibly.

Comment: Hopefully this cleared it up, I get the same result with a straight link to the css (its basically what .net ends up doing). Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BootstrapCDN is supported by JSFiddle, you just need to paste in the relevant URLs.

In the external resource field/box enter each of these URLs* and hit +:

```
https://bootswatch.com/4/minty/bootstrap.css
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
```

and in html section you should write that :

```
<div class="bs-component">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </nav>
        <div id="source-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="display: none;">&lt; &gt;</div></div>
```

Comment: Tank you Irakli! So it seems the original tutorial's code was not really complete enough to work as he showed it?

Comment: An additional thing I discovered, the tutorial is a little older, and if I used the  version 3 of the minty bootstrap, it worked with the .net project's original html code. Thank you everyone for your help!